# Offline multi-city International public transport app?

Tags: public-transport, cities, software

Some years ago, before Android and iOS, I used to have a map for Windows phone (and web) that allowed you to download per-city packs of subway information that included schedules and connection information for cities around the world.

You were able to enter two stations, one to start and one to go to and it would plot you all possible subway connections between the two points.

I have been looking quite a lot now on the internet and the Android app store for something like this, bought even a couple and refunded them. Most of them simply are a collection of maps where you have to trace the route yourself instead of having a real "navigation" for subways.

As far as I remember the application I used to have was called "Metro". It was not open-source IIRC but the data was provided by the users. Anyone remember this? Does it or something similar exist?

Comment: Aside from Google Maps, which covers many major cities?

Comment: Google maps is barely accurate with public transport. I have sent them numerous corrections for routes in Birmingham, AL and Darwin, NT. Corrections that which they have, thankfully,  implemented, but who knows what public transport timings, worldwide, are still off.

Comment: @happybuddha: Google Maps uses [GTFS](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/) format data files that are made available by each transit provider. The quality of the data in Google Maps depends almost entirely on the quality of data provided by the people who run the transit system. I'm actually surprised that corrections you submitted were implemented, perhaps Google fed them back to the GTFS creator.

Comment: It works fantastically for me in London, Vancouver, Sydney, Canberra and Perth, but sadly not Melbourne (VPT hasn't opened up access properly, much to the chagrin of a fellow developer I know who wants to use it)

Comment: I wanted something that works offline. Let me clarify above.

Comment: @GregHewgill uhmm, not only public transport but they also get driving directions wrong occasionally. Yours truly, has helped them with that as well. To take the edge off your surprise, you can download the bus routes of Darwin from the NT site and compare the timings with google maps. As an eg., you could search for public transit between Woolies (Cavanagh St.) to Woolies (Casuarina). IMHO it would be naive to trust everything online, even if its transit directions.

Comment: @happybuddha: I'm certainly not saying I blindly trust everything online. The GTFS data sets I've seen are, shall we say, of varying quality. I haven't had occasion to use the one for Darwin, but I believe you if you say it's not quite accurate.

Comment: Google maps works great for public transport in some cities (Atlanta, USA), not at all in some (Guadalajara, Mexico), and partially in others (London, UK). I can clearly see a need for something better.

Comment: @MarkMayo: In London, google maps doesn't (as of Nov 2013) include any routes for the national rail service, even though it's included (within London) on the Oyster card at the same rates as the Tube, DLR, and Overground services.  Thus I give it a "partially working" rating in my comment above.

Comment: If Google Maps transit information are inaccurate, it's unlikely that it will be accurate in another map (Waze might be a rescue though). Tripso has several apps for each city with offline maps and GPS indication of where you are, but not sure about traffic and directions. For popular cities, you'll find many charts with bus and train timetables. Good luck!

Comment: @Ayesh yes, because if google can't do it, it must be *impossible.*

Comment: @AyeshK: I beg to differ.  In Guadalajara, Mexico, google maps has exactly zero information about public transport. But the city publishes their own web site and mobile app with accurate public transport maps (using google maps as the mapping engine). Countless other cities also offer their own public transport app and/or website. So claiming that "if google doesn't do it, nobody does" is clearly inaccurate.

Comment: I didn't say Google is a king or anything - local travel companies surely have their own sites to publish their own time tables but when it comes to multiple cities, you definitely need some standard, which Google is already following. Although not completely offline, it atleast fulfills sorta multi-city and International part, right :) (I'm also a software developer and it's a dream to be somewhere new everyweek!)

Comment: Google is as accurate as the public transport data provider wants them to be. They're merely parsing the data, not creating it from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Ha! I finally found it! The app is not in the Android App store, but it works fine. The software is called "[Metro](http://metro.nanika.net/index.php?p=MetroHH)" as I remembered, it's offline and works quite nicely with 400 cities.

Answer (score 2):

In an amusing coincidence, the Melbourne subreddit today deviated into a discussion on transport apps, and one of the ones suggested was [Offi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schildbach.oeffi) - a multi-city public transport app.

The cities/countries it claims to support:

Supported countries:

> • Europe • United Kingdom • Ireland • USA (San Francisco,
>   Philadelphia) • Australia (Sydney, New South Wales, Melbourne,
>   Victoria) • Germany • Austria • Switzerland • Belgium • Luxembourg •
>   Liechtenstein • Netherlands (Amsterdam) • Denmark • Sweden • Norway
>   (Oslo & Bergen) • Poland
>
> Supported Cities and Regions:
>
> • London • Birmingham • Dublin • San Francisco • Philadelphia • Sydney
>   • Melbourne • Dubai • Jerusalem • Berlin & Brandenburg • Frankfurt &
>   Rhine-Main • Munich (München) • Augsburg • Schwerin &
>   Mecklenburg-Vorpommern • Kiel, Lübeck & Schleswig-Holstein • Hannover
>   & Lower Saxony • Braunschweig • Bremen • Bremerhaven & Oldenburg •
>   Leipzig & Saxony-Anhalt • Dresden • Chemnitz & Mittelsachsen • Essen,
>   Dortmund, Düsseldorf & Rhine-Ruhr • Cologne (Köln), Bonn (network
>   plans only!) • Lüdenscheid & Märkischer Kreis • Paderborn & Höxter •
>   Mannheim & Rhine-Neckar • Stuttgart • Reutlingen & Neckar-Alb-Donau •
>   Ulm • Karlsruhe • Trier • Nuremberg (Nürnberg), Fürth & Erlangen •
>   Würzburg & Regensburg • Strasbourg & Freiburg • Baden-Württemberg •
>   Plauen & Vogtland • Vienna (Wien) • Linz • Salzburg • Innsbruck • Graz
>   & Styria • Bregenz & Vorarlberg • Basel • Lucerne (Luzern) • Zurich
>   (Zürich) • Brussels (Brüssel) • Copenhagen (Kopenhagen) • Stockholm •
>   Warsaw (Warschau) • Maribor
>
> and more...

I tried out the Melbourne aspect of it, since our apps are notriously poor, and so far I'm quite impressed...